# Change css class properties with another as dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap css tooltip class that defined like this:

```
    .tooltip{display:none;color:#000;text-align:left;}
    .tooltip.in{opacity:0.9;z-index:1030;height:auto;display:block}
    .tooltip.top{margin-top:-10px;text-align:center}
    .tooltip.top{margin-top:-10px;text-align:center}
    .tooltip.right{margin-left:10px} 
    ...
```

I want to create different version of `.tooltip` class. Red, Blue, Orange and others.

I want to create classes

```
.red-tooltip{display:none;color:red;text-align:left;}
.red-tooltip.in{opacity:0.9;z-index:1030;height:auto;display:block}
.red-tooltip.top{margin-top:-8px;text-align:center}
.red-tooltip.top{margin-top:-7px;text-align:center}
.red-tooltip.right{margin-left:6px}

.blue-tooltip{display:none;color:blue;text-align:left;}
.blue-tooltip.in{opacity:0.9;z-index:1030;height:auto;display:block}
.blue-tooltip.top{margin-top:-18px;text-align:center}
.blue-tooltip.top{margin-top:-27px;text-align:center}
.blue-tooltip.right{margin-left:6px}
```

How can I dynamically change `.tooltip` content with `.blue-tooltip`

Can I do this via jquery?

Comment: Your question is not clear, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: How do you imagine the dynamic part should work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch one class to an other one, you can use:

```
$('.tooltip').toggleClass('tooltip blue-tooltip');
```

This would switch all `.tooltip` elements to `blue-tooltip` class.

Now if you want to specifcally set it to blue, red or whatever color, you need to be more specfic using your selector.

Comment: I want to change .tooltip content with .blue-tooltip.

Comment: That's what it is doing, if i understand what you mean